# Event calls and Scope issues

Tags: javascript, scope, dom-events, raphael

I'm trying to create an easy play / pause button system with Raphael but I keep getting scope issues.

The buttons themselves are just images embed in the SVG tag thanks to Raphael.
The goal is to have this "event cycle" :

- If play.png is displayed, `onmouseover` `remove()` play.png and show play-hover.png
- If play-hover.png is displayed, `onclick` `remove()` play-hover.png show pause.png
- If pause.png is displayed, `onmouseover` `remove()` pause.png show pause-hover.png
- If pause-hover.png is displayed, `onclick` `remove()` pause-hover.png show play.png

It seems really stupid but I really have problems with scope and closures. This is the code I have at the moment :

```
  function toPlay(pauseHover) {
    pauseHover.remove();
    var play = paper.image("images/play.png", Img.X, Img.Y, Img.height, Img.width);
    play.node.onmouseover = toPlayHover(play);
  }
  
  function toPause(playHover) {
    playHover.remove();
    var pause = paper.image("images/pause.png", Img.X, Img.Y, Img.height, Img.width);
    pause.node.onmouseover = toPauseHover(pause);
  }
  
  function toPlayHover(play) {
    play.remove();
    var playHover = paper.image("images/play-hover.png", Img.X, Img.Y, Img.height, Img.width);
    playHover.node.onclick = toPause(playHover);
  }
  
  function toPauseHover(pause) {
    pause.remove();
    var pauseHover = paper.image("images/pause-hover.png", Img.X, Img.Y, Img.height, Img.width);
    pauseHover.node.onclick = toPlay(pauseHover);
  }
  
  var play = paper.image("images/play.png", Img.X, Img.Y, Img.height, Img.width);
  toPlayHover(play);
```

I don't know exactly why this doesn't work since firebug isn't giving me any errors in the console, but I think it's because the `toPlayHover()` function can't be called within the `toPlay()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are immediately calling each function instead of registering it as a callback. To fix, wrap each callback in an anonymous function like so:

```
play.node.onmouseover = function() { toPlayHover(play); };
```

Comment: Ouaou, thank you a lot ! I would have have never thought about this in a million years ! I fixed it and it works !